# Как предотвратить редирект страницы при ajax запросе?

Tags: yii2

В `GridView` отображены лоты и он обернут `Pjax`:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'lots']); ?>
```

На каждой строке `GridView` расположена следующая кнопка:

```
return Html::a('Подать цену', null, [
  'value' => Url::to(['create', 'id' => $model->id]),
  'class' => 'bidButton',
]);
```

При нажатии на каждой кнопке открывается модальное окно и подгружается url из кнопки:

```
Modal::begin([
  'header' => '<h4>Подать цену</h4>',
  'id' => 'bidModal',
  'size' => 'modal-md',
]);
echo '<div id="bidModalContent"></div>';
Modal::end();

$this->registerJs(
  "$('.bidButton').click(function() {
    $('#bidModal').modal('show')
      .find('#bidModalContent')
      .load($(this).attr('value'));
  });", 
  View::POS_READY, 'bid'
);
```

Соответствующий `action` в контроллерре, который подгружается в модальное окно:

```
public function actionCreate($id)
{
  //поиск лота, на который будет подана цена и прочая валидация
  $lot = $this->findLot($id);

  $entry = new Entry();
  $entry->lot_id = $id;

  if($entry->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $entry->save();
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ['code' => 100];
  } 

  return $this->renderAjax('modals/create', [
    'entry' => $entry,
  ]);
}
```

Форма create:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-entry']); ?>
<?= $form->field($entry, 'price')->textInput() ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Подать', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

На этой же форме перехватчик события `beforeSubmit`:

```
$this->registerJs(
"$('#bidModal').on('beforeSubmit', 'form-entry', function () {
  var form = $(this);
  data.push({
    name: '_csrf',
    value: '" . Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken() . "'
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      $('#bidModal').modal('hide');
      $.pjax.reload({container: '#lots'});
    }
  });
  return false;
});",
View::POS_READY, 'submit');
```

С этим перехватом отправляется ajax запрос, вызывается action, создается и сохраняется `Entry()`. Но в конце - вместо того, чтобы отправив успешный ответ, скрыть модальное окно и обновить `GridView` обернутый в `Pjax`, страница перенаправлятся в на `create?id=X` со следующим содержимым: `{"code":100}`.
Как предотвратить перенаправление и воплотить в работу то, что я задумал?

Comment: Потому что отрабатывает обычный сабмит формы. Бефорсабмит кажется не отменяет отправку формы. Возможно надо перехватывать сразу сабмит.

Comment: Вы правы. Сделал так: `$('#form-entry').submit(function () {` и все получилось.